# Python - Bytes, \x and Struct

Tags: python, networking, struct, byte, packet

I have recently been creating a basic packet sniffer to develop my knowledge of Python.

The output I produce for a packet is:
`b'E\x00\x00(\x9dS@\x008\x069\xfbh\xc7@\x88\xc0\xa8\x01\x8a\x01\xbb\xc5.\xd7\xd98\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x04\x00\x00m\x95\x00\x00'`

This is a byte that I have then decoded using the `struct` module however when looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) for `struct` you can see the examples they use are relatively simple. I mean that its always an `\x`(escape sequence) followed by two digits and thats it. In my example you often have other symbols such as (, @ or just another digit added to the \x), how does struct handle these?

Comment: `\x` indicates Hexadecimal.

Comment: How can you have @ or ( following the '\x' as this is not a valid Hexadecimal character?